# Unable to display an Image in html (404 error)

Tags: css, html, image

I am just trying to display an image inside  . But image is broken when i run the code. In console `GET http://localhost:29499/Views/ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I am confused why such a simple code isn't wroking. Please help

Code:

```
 <div class="row div_Align">
   <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="col-md-12 panel-heading">
         <div>
           <img src="~/Views/ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg" />
         </div>         
       </div>
       <!-- /.panel-body -->
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: are running command locally ?  is the service at the specific port working ?

Comment: Yes. I have added the image inside project and added the exact location

Comment: so where is the image located than ? and what is the connection with the GET command image not found ?

Comment: your image path is incorrect or image type extension not correct

Comment: are you using `mvc` or `asp.net`? how `~` can be interpreted as `localhost` and some path? and if mvc then are you having image in `view` directory? if yes, then thats not the right thing, you should have in `content` of `image` folder.  Of course not in `controller` and `views` directory

Comment: I changed the extension of image to gif. Its working now :D I am not sure why other extensions didn't work.

Comment: your image type is .gif. so work only .gif extension only

Comment: @shreyPav, upload your folder path from where the image is coming.. something like projectname->assets->images->imagename.jpg... or get image link from google and add in your HTML and check it. because your code is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is RESOLVED
I had to change the file extension to `gif`.

Comment: This is not a solution. if the gif is working then why jpg, png not working?

Answer (score 3):

Try Replacing this:

```
<img src="~/Views/ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg" />
```

With this:

```
<img src="/Views/ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg" />
```

The image path should be relative to sever root directory not the system root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the relative path:
 `<img src="~/Views/ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg" />`

Try with an absolute path of where the file exists, similar to this

`<img src="file:///D://abc//Views//ImageOrgChart/Org_Chart.jpg" />`